# Deploy springboot jar using jenkins

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins . I would like to do small POC. I've springboot maven project in github. Can anyone please let me know how / provide helpufl links to deploy the jar in my local using jenkins .

Thanks
Somi J.

Comment: ```to deploy the jar in my local``` what you mean by this ?
what exactly is your goal ? 
do you want to check out from github and build locally ?

Comment: Yes.. run the jar also in my local

Comment: well, there is two cases I can imaging why you would use jenkins for that: 1. to have continuesly executable/refreshable artifact on you local machine per push to git repository for any/specific branch. 2. to build locally and updaload somewhere. If you want to execute the jar/war file locally under some schedule or so, just create job which will isten to repo, pull and build and then start/stop service